# Azure CLI AKS creation with Application Gateway: how to show details?

Tags: azure, azure-cli, terraform-provider-azure

I am attempting to reverse engineer this command so I can move it into Terraform:

```
az aks create --resource-group "..." --name "..." \
  --network-plugin azure \
  --enable-managed-identity \
  -a ingress-gateway --appgw-name "myAksGateway" --appgw-subnet-id "..." \
  --node-vm-size "..." \
  --service-cidr "..." \
  --vnet-subnet-id "..." \
  --docker-bridge-address "..." \
  --dns-service-ip "..." \
  --generate-ssh-keys
```

Everything is going fine except for the Application Gateway part.

**Is there any way to ask the Azure CLI to do a dry run and simply show me all the creation data it is using?**

I looked at `az aks create --help` but it didn't have a dry run option.

The basics for [azurerm_kubernetes_cluster](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/kubernetes_cluster) are straight-forward, as is the [azurerm_application_gateway](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/application_gateway); something is off and I want to see what it is doing under the covers to get it just right. There's some differences I am trying to get ironed out and it would be much easier to just see what it's doing.

I can't run `az aks create --debug` because of resource limits and the basic JSON output on the AKS resource isn't verbose enough for what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get all the creating data from the CLI command even if you use the parameter `--debug`, it only shows you the REST API behind the CLI command. You can get all the steps to install the AGIC for the AKS cluster [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ingress-controller-install-new). Then you can transfer all the steps into Terraform.